# How can I tell which parts of my car are "By Wire"?

Tags: electrical, honda, steering

I've recently purchased a manual transmission 1.5 litre Honda Mobilio. It is claimed to be a drive by wire vehicle and I assume it really is, but I don't know how to tell if a car is drive by wire.

I am a new driver and not sure which parts of a drive-by-wire really is "by-wire". I am aware (from my [previous questions](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/q/25937/675) here) that when specs say "Drive-by-wire" it does not necessarily mean all (brakes, steering, gas,clutch). My question is, how to identify which ones?

Information like this would be helpful when you decide to resell your brand new car. :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*Note: this answer only addresses drive-by-wire; I don't know if you could tell whether the other systems employ by-wire technologies as readily.*

### Drive-By-Wire : Look at your throttle body

*If it has a throttle plate actuated by cable, you have drive-by-cable, not drive-by-wire*

***Drive-by-cable examples:***

[image: Honda S2000]

[image: LS1 Throttle Body]

***Drive-by-wire examples:***

*Notice the absence of a spring-loaded cable-actuator*

[image: Suzuki Swift Supercharged DBW]

[image: BMW Electronic Throttle Body]

Comment: "By wire" brakes are only found on hybrids and they usually use a combination of by wire and hydraulic. There is no such thing as by wire steering as there will always be a mechanical link between the rack and the steering shaft. Electric power steering is done either as a motor attached to the rack or on the steering shaft.